# JavascriptError: TypeError: cyclic object value .... Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am getting below error when I run my test cases in Protractor

```
JavascriptError: TypeError: cyclic object value
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'SH********01', ip: '172.18.221.191', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

this issue is happening w.r.t all the browsers

**config file -**

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['spec.js'],
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',
},
allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
}
};
```

**spec.js**

```
var v = require('./Pagedata/Local/url.json')
describe('Login the app', function () {

  var username = element(by.model('vm.user.username'));
  var password = element(by.model('vm.user.password'));
  var signin = element(by.xpath("//button[contains(text(),Sign)]"));

  it('test', function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get(v.url);
    waitforpagetoload();
    // username.click()
    username.sendKeys('43731');
    // password.click()
    password.sendKeys('43731');

    signin.click();
  });
});
```

**url.json**

```
{
"url":"http://www.mywebsi.....e.com"
}
```

I have updated the npm and node js, still facing the same issue

I have added my code here

Comment: Can you please share some more details like conf file and test cases so that we can debug more.

Comment: i have added the code  above plz have a look

Comment: can you ping url.json too? looks like some object is referring each other and creating cyclic dependency.

Comment: I have the same case for login in my project, I see that you are not setting browser.ignoreSynchronization = false; after the signin button, did you try to set back to false after the login? if I dont do this at least for me some weird errors are displayed when angular is loaded

Comment: @YashJagdale i have added the url file data.

Comment: @Alexandre I had tried even your approach but no use. then i add to remove reverting back from setting browser.ignoreSynchrinization=false, since in my project some serves keep on running at the backend